# Crystal Report not updating the design

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am working on MVC project using Crystal Report with Visual Studio 2013. I designed some reports a long time ago (using Crystal Report in VS2012 to design). Now I want to change the layout of the report but when I run the report, it still use the old layout. I also tried to remove some fields in the report and run again. However, the report still displayed those fields when running.

Comment: are you running the report on crystal or using another software? If you are using VS make sure you are doing check in and out.

Comment: I am running the report by running the project. What do you mean check in and out?

Comment: I thought you were open it on VS. Make sure that you are replacing the report where your project is accesing to it once you do those changes.

Comment: Its quite possible the new report is being saved at a different location to that of what is being used by your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot to re-import the sub-reports to the main report when I made some changes.